# Get value from data-section based on element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'd like to render the section id="zero" data-section **value** in the h2 in my footer section dynamically. Since all of my pages will have different data-section values, I'm hoping we can target the section id="zero". This way I can use only one footer across my site. I am just not versed in javascript or jQuery to properly assign and call. I know there is  document.getElementById('zero') but then getting the value from data-section and having it appear within my H2 I am not clear on.

```
<section id="zero" class="section-wrap" data-section="Page Name"></section>

<section id="footer">
<h2></h2>
</section>
```

Comment: why the negative?

Comment: Not that I downvoted, but probably because there hasn't been an attempt to solve what you're asking. You know about one JS command `document.getElementById('zero')` - start there, make some attempts, and when you get stuck on a specific problem, post about that specific problem. Right now, you're kind of just asking us to do it for you.

Comment: no idea about the downvote. Do you want to do this using jquery or vanilla js?

Comment: @AdityaParab whichever is the most elegant solution.

Comment: @tymeJV I've tried several things, I understand. Is there a method like document.get Data Attribute?  I tried...document.getElementById('zero').querySelectorAll('[data-section]');

Comment: @sloga - You can get the element via `getElementById` then use the method `getAttribute` to get specific attributes off the element.

Comment: @sloga: aright. is there gonna be only one section on a page with `data-section` attribute?

Comment: Can you post your attempts?

Comment: @AdityaParab there are multiple section with the data-section attribute so that's why I need to target the unique id of "zero"

Comment: @jhpratt I've been testing in w3schools tryit editor and been through several different iterations. I'll try to paste everything I've tried momentarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some Javascript that should help.

```
//Get the data-section value
let val = document.getElementById('zero').dataset.section; 

//find the first h2 inside footer section
let header = document.getElementById('footer').getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];

//set the value
header.textContent = val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS way

```
function start(){

  // Find element with id="zero"
  const section = document.querySelector('#zero');

  // Find the h2 element nested inside an element with id="footer"
  const footer = document.querySelector('#footer h2');

  // Get value of data-section attribute
  const dataSectionValue = section.getAttribute('data-section');

  // Set value in your h2 tag
  footer.innerText = dataSectionValue;
}

window.onload = start;
```

jQuery way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  const section = $('#zero');

  $('#footer h2').text(section.data('section'));
});
```

Comment: I appreciate this but I couldn't get the jQuery way to work.